# Ajaxfileupload and images

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, file-upload

i'm not able to upload my image why? i'm having this error can someone help please, i'm really lost on that since a week please

```
        If Page.IsPostBack = False Then
        ' Getting the File Name 
        Dim filename As String = e.FileName

        ' Setting the path to upload Images

        AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("images/") & filename)

        ' Storing the relative path to store into images
        Dim Imagepath As String = "~/Seller/images/" & filename
        Dim conss As New SqlConnection(_start)
        conss.Open()


        Dim sql1 As String = "INSERT INTO Image(Image,ItemID) VALUES (@image,@item)"
        Dim myCommand1 = New SqlCommand(sql1, conss)

        myCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", Imagepath)
        myCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item", dbItem.SelectedValue)
        myCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Response.Redirect("ItemView.aspx")
```

[image]

```
<div>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Select Auction:"></asp:Label> <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"><ContentTemplate><asp:DropDownList ID="dbItem" AutoPostBack="true"  DataValueField="ItemID" DataTextField="Name"  
                runat="server" >

            </asp:DropDownList></ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="myThrobber" Style="display: none;"></asp:Label>
    <asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" ThrobberID="myThrobber" MaximumNumberOfFiles="4" AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg" runat="server" />
</div>
```

Comment: Can you get any more information about the error other than the word "error"?  Is there an exception on the server-side code?  A specific error in the HTTP response?  An error in the JavaScript code?  You'll need to do a little debugging here.

Comment: You've talked about the AjaxFileUpload but have only given us code behind... if it's an issue with the control we need the control!

Comment: Check that the application has write access to the location ~/Seller/images/.... your application will be running under a user in my case NetworkServices - just make sure that this user has read/write access to the upload directory.

Comment: @user3287068 the reason you're not getting a lot of answers on this ticket is because you're not telling us what the error message is or where it's coming from. Without it we're guessing

Comment: the problem is that my self i don't i tried to upload the file and it flow and error and when i make inspect element in my browser

Comment: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Comment: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Chloé\AppData\Local\Temp\_AjaxFileUpload\6B5BDB68-9EC0-D98B-7BA0-28077B1BB1BD

Answer (score 0):

in folder web.config . . . add this part

```
<configuration>
   <location path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd">
       <system.web>
          <authorization>
             <allow users="*"/>
          </authorization>
       </system.web>
   </location>
```

in root web.config , add this handler

```
 <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
       <add verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit"/>
    </httpHandlers>
```

**while developing , if you are using windows7 or windows8 , run visual studio *AS ADMINISTRATOR***